# Celery halts after 16000 tasks

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am using Celery 3.1.17, RabbitMQ server as broker, backend disabled.

Celery settings:

```
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True

CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True

CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True

CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True

CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 1
```

The broker is hosted on a separate server.

```
RabbitMQ server configuration : 2GB RAM, dual core

Codebase server : 8 GB RAM, quad core
```

Celery worker settings:

```
Workers : 4

Concurrency : 12

Memory Consumption in the codebase server : 2GB (max)

CPU Load in codebase server : 4.5, 2.1, 1.5

Tasks Fired : 50,000

Publishing Rate : 1000/s
```

Problem :

After every 16,000 tasks, the worker halts for about 1-2 minutes and then restarts.

Also about 200-300 tasks had failed.

CPU and memory consumption are NOT bottlenecks in this case.

Is it a ulimits thing?
How do I ensure that constant execution rate of tasks and prevent messages from getting lost?